# Return specific map entry instead of map::end if no map entry was found

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

In a switch statement, you can specify a default return value if none of the other cases apply.
I'd like to do something similar with std::map, but I'm not sure if it is possible:
Can I make the map return a specific value/entry instead of map::end if no key fits the search?

Example (Here is what I'd ultimatively like to do - I am aware that the code doesn't work):

```
std::map<std::string, void* (*) (DataObject*)> commands; //Mapping functions to keys
commands["Test"] = function(DataObject d){doSomething();}
commands[Nothing else applies] = function(DataObject d){doSomethingElse();}

commands.find("Test")(someDataObject); // doSomething(); happens
commands.find("blabla")(someDataObject); //doSomethingElse(); happens because no other entry was found
```

Would something like that be possible?

(Also, the way I'm using function pointers in this example probably doesn't work at all - Can I use cpp11's lambda expressions to accomplish what I want to do?)

I do NOT want to use a switch clause, nor do I want an `if(m.find(x) != m.end())` clause, nor do I want even more if-else's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own functor with a default value:

```
struct MyFunctor: public std::function<void(DataObject*)> {

    template <typename F>
    MyFunctor (F &&f) : std::function<void(DataObject*)> (std::forward<F> (f)) { }

    MyFunctor () : std::function<void(DataObject*)> (doSomethingElse) { }

};
```

Assuming `doSomethingElse` is a already defined function.

Then you can simply do:

```
std::map<std::string, MyFunctor> commands; //Mapping functions to keys
commands["Test"] = [] (DataObject *) { }; // Assign from lambda

DataObject *myDataObject= new DataObject();
commands["Not Defined"] (myDataObject); // Call doSomethingElse
```

---

You can easily have different default values (defined at compile time) using a template for `MyFunctor`:

```
template <void (*DefaultFn) (DataObject*)>
struct MyFunctor: public std::function<void(DataObject*)> {

    template <typename F>
    MyFunctor (F &&f) : std::function<void(DataObject*)> (std::forward<F> (f)) { }

    MyFunctor () : std::function<void(DataObject*)> (DefaultFn) { }

};

std::map<std::string, MyFunctor<doSomethingElse>> commands;
```

Comment: Wow, this looks awesome, thank you! I'd just have to truly understand it now, haha. (Coming from a Java background, a lot of C++ stuff is still new to me)

Comment: Would you mind explaining me what the "&&" exactly means in this case? I read that it stands for a RValue, but I haven't gotten the use of it in this situation. Also, how exactly does the "overwriting" work (Per definition, the value for each key in the map should be of MyFunctor type, but the code allows to simply overwrite it with a lambda - Which is good, but how does it work?) - Wait, nvm, it's because MyFunctor inherits from function, right? So when we pass a lambda, MyFunctor gets constructed with that lambda, which then calls the forward method? Last one: Why struct instead of class?

Comment: @user2065501 `&&` is a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) here, meaning that it can takes lvalue or rvalue and do perfect forwarding (you should not really worry about it in this code). The code as it is allows you to construct a `MyFunctor` using anything that can be passed to the constructor of a `std::function`, which a lambda is (when you assign a lambda, you create a new `MyFunctor` with the given lambda, which simply pass it to its parent `std::function`). `struct` instead of `class` is just habit, use `class` if you want.

Comment: Oh, and also: With the templated version at the end of your post, is there a possibility to "create" doSomethingElse in the same line as the map declaration? Basically, `std::map<std::string, MyFunctor<[](DataObject*){}>>`? I tried it, lambda isn't allowed, but is there another possibility?

Comment: No it is not possible in this case because the parameter you give has to be a available at compile time (a lambda is not).

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot have that functionality with `std::map` as `std::map::find()` returns iterator equal to `end()` when the key is not found and you cannot dereference it. So you either need to use `if( m.find( "blah" ) == m.end() )` clause or use something else that `std::map` or write your own class with functionality you demand.

You may though have special value type which default state will have functionality you need and then access it through `std::map::operator[]` not `std::map::find()` but that will have side effect - for each key you searched new entry will be added to the map. I doubt that would be better solution than having one `if()` clause but that is up to you.